# RuntimeError: lost sys.stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-internals

I was trying to debug an issue with `abc.ABCMeta` - in particular a subclass check that didn't work as expected and I wanted to start by simply adding a `print` to the `__subclasscheck__` method (I know there are better ways to debug code, but pretend for the sake of this question that there's no alternative). However when starting Python afterwards Python crashes (like a segmentation fault) **and** I get this exception:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\lib\io.py", line 84, in <module>
  File "C:\...\lib\abc.py", line 158, in register
  File "C:\...\lib\abc.py", line 196, in __subclasscheck__
RuntimeError: lost sys.stdout
```

So it probebly wasn't a good idea to put the `print` in there. But where exactly does the exception come from? I only changed Python code, that shouldn't crash, right?

Does someone know where this exception is coming from and if/how I can avoid it but still put a `print` in the `abc.ABCMeta.__subclasscheck__` method?

I'm using Windows 10, Python-3.5 (just in case it might be important).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exception stems from the fact that CPython [imports `io`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a77a35d70ba8aed047e63d4d9f7d0554e98d4c4b/Python/pylifecycle.c#L1586), and, indirectly, `abc.py` during the [initialization of the standard streams](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a77a35d70ba8aed047e63d4d9f7d0554e98d4c4b/Python/pylifecycle.c#L784):

```c
if (!(iomod = PyImport_ImportModule("io"))) {
    goto error;
}
```

`io` imports the `abc` module and [registers `FileIO`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dfd5f34634f9c505945e9348b4b799544680a7cf/Lib/io.py#L84) as a virtual subclass of `RawIOBase`, a couple of other classes for `BufferedIOBase` and others for `TextIOBase`. `ABCMeta.register` invokes  `__subclasscheck__` in the process.

As you understand, using `print` in `__subclasscheck__` when `sys.stdout` *isn't* set-up is a big no-no; the initialization fails and you get back your error:

```c
if (initstdio() < 0)
    Py_FatalError(
        "Py_NewInterpreter: can't initialize sys standard streams");
```

You can get around it by guarding it with a `hasattr(sys, 'stdout')`, `sys` has been initialized by this point while `stdout` hasn't (and, as such, won't exist in `sys` in the early initialization phase):

```
if hasattr(sys, 'stdout'):
    print("Debug")
```

you should get good amount of output when firing Python up now.

Comment: Sharing in case it helps someone: I named one of my module io.py, which was not a good idea considering that CPython imports an io module already!