# pycharm RuntimeError: lost sys.stdout ,how to fix this?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've just download Pycharm community Edition 2017.1.5 and when I debug my code it give me this Error in console

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python36\lib\io.py", line 52, in &lt;module>

File "C:\Users\w\temp\abc.py", line 5, in &lt;module>

RuntimeError: lost sys.stdout
```

io.py

```
import abc
```

abc.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s1 = 72
s2 = 85
r = (s2 - s1)/s1 *100
print ('%.1f %%' % r)
```

Why would this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to rename your file `abc.py` into something else : [see here the details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987751/runtimeerror-lost-sys-stdout)

Comment: i've watched that,but i still don't understand why i got this exception,and i don't think our problem is same one ,as he says he changed something,but i did't change anthing,why rename abc.py?should i rename the abc.py in IO.py too?sorry ,i'm a new guy,don't understand that much things,can you help me .

Comment: did you modify the file `io.py` in `C:\Python36\lib\io.py` ?

Answer (score 8):

i could reproduce the issue by naming any file abc.py and execute from PyCharm, it looks like there is a conflict with this file name.

ABC is a standard module used by Python, and imported in many others modules like `io`, used in the standard *inputs* and *outputs*. When executing your script, it seems to import your code instead of the standard module.

It should works if you rename your own module `abc.py` in something else, i.e 
`abcd.py`