# Python literally just won't run

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm having this error when calling python

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = 'C:\Users\iamco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib'
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\iamco\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\iamco\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\iamco\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311'
  sys.platlibdir = 'DLLs'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\iamco\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\iamco\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\iamco\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\iamco\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\iamco\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
    'C:\\Users\\iamco\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iamco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\iamco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\aliases.py", line 552, in <module>
RuntimeError: lost sys.stdout
```

I haven't found anything online about this.
I was running some python files and I got this.
I tried multiple files, but I think it's a python file.

I tried multiple files
More than py3

Comment: python ERROR* ()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987751/runtimeerror-lost-sys-stdout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122480/pycharm-runtimeerror-lost-sys-stdout-how-to-fix-this

Comment: check your environment variable or trying reinstalling the python. You might make a slight move with your libs files in python.

Comment: How did you run Python exactly? Which Python files?

Comment: Please post the names of all the `.py` files in the current directory.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is likely that this error can be caused by an incorrect configuration of the **Python** environment or a violation of the integrity of system files. Incorrect Python path configuration or system file corruption can cause the **sys.stdout** object to be lost or incorrectly initialized.

Here is few possible solutions to this problem:

1. Reinstall Python: Try reinstalling Python to update or repair broken files and settings.
2. Check the environment: Make sure the **PYTHONHOME** and **PYTHONPATH** environment variables are set correctly. They must point to the correct Python directories.
3. Set Defaults: Make sure you don't have any custom code or settings that could change or corrupt standard output (**sys.stdout**). Check that there is no misuse of the sys.stdout object in your code.